# Loading json File in a HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a JSON file which contains HTML content. I want to load it in my main HTML file when a user clicks on a button.

`ABC.json` contains:

```
<li><img src="images/picture6.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="images/picture5.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="images/picture4.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="images/picture3.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="images/picture2.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="images/picture1.jpg" /></li>
```

The Javascript code that I'm using is:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("javascript/lib/domain.json", function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: if it contains just HTMLthen why dont you make it .html?

Comment: your json file is not json _

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file `ABC.json` does not contain any valid JSON.

I think it's worthwhile visiting http://www.json.org/ You will get a better idea about json and how to use it.

Specifically you will find the way to pass html within json in different languages

Comment: Although I feel that the original poster, saorabh should visit this site to see what JSON actually consists of, I don't feel that this is a legitimate answer; you're just pointing him to a link. Instead, you should explain what he's doing wrong or why it can't be done (if that is the case).

Answer (score 2):

Please edit your code:

**abc.json**

```
"img": [
        {"src": "images/picture6.jpg"},
        {"src": "images/picture5.jpg"},
        {"src": "images/picture4.jpg"},
        {"src": "images/picture3.jpg"},
        {"src": "images/picture2.jpg"},
        {"src": "images/picture1.jpg"},
       ]
```

**Javascript**

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("javascript/lib/abc.json", function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your .json file contains pure html and not JSON. Why not use `.html` or `.txt` instead?

Or you can try this:

```
var my_html = $.parseJSON(data);
console.log(my_html);
```

Comment: First thanks Jhon.. Can you please guide me if I make it as a html file,then how I can achieve this.

Comment: If it is already an html file, then you can load it by using for example the following:

$.load('list.html',function(data){
console.log(data);
});

or

$.get('list.html',function(data){
console.log(data);
});